# Cannot install packages in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, installation, package, joomla3.0

I installed a Joomla 3.6.5 and now I cannot install any packages.
And this is the error I've got :

> Unable to find install package

[image]

This happens when I click on '*Add "Install from Web" tab*' button too!

I tried reinstalling and upgrading to 3.8.5 but nothing changed! I can install nothing!

Update:
Folder permissions:
[image]

Comment: Did you check this answer? https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16999/jfoldercreate-path-not-in-open-basedir-paths-unable-to-create-destination

Comment: Also check https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/161/120

Answer (score 1):

Anything related to installation error, you should check

1. Your temp file location is correct or not
2. Your temp folder has appropriate permission or not.

You can attach screenshot of your folder permissions here.

Comment: The permision of tmp folder is 755. I changed it to 777 but nothing changed!

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions.

(1) The problem may be because **upload_tmp_dir** isn't set in your PHP config.

Look in SYSTEM > SYSTEM INFORMATION > PHP INFORMATION and check if upload_tmp_dir has been set. If not, you need to edit php.ini

On our servers (which use open base dir), the setting is:

```
upload_tmp_dir=/tmp
```

Depending on your server configuration, this value could be different for you.

(2) The other place to check is the value in SYSTEM > GLOBAL CONFIGURATION > SERVER

If you haven't already done so, try using the full server path to the tmp directory, rather than say a path relative to your home directory.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The temp folder is not where you have told Joomla it is.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old topic, but maybe my solution might be helpful for someone...

> Error: Unable to find install package (and other errors like that)

is nothing more than permissions error check... So, you have to give right permissions to yourself for:

- /var/www/html/nameofyoursite/languages,
- /var/www/html/nameofyoursite/tmp,
- /var/www/html/nameofyoursite/administrator/languages,
- /var/www/html/nameofyoursite/administrator/manifest/everythinginmanifestfolder,
- /var/www/html/nameofyoursite/administrator/modules,
- /var/www/html/nameofyoursite/administrator/logs.

That's it! Now you can install languages and everything else...

(I found this solution yesterday, and cp my answer from joomla's forum)

Comment: That topic is so old and I cannot check it anymore. But thanks for your answer and, welcome to Stack Overflow